# center table in page HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center this header in the middle of the page. Not sure why `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` isn't working. It won't register `align:center` either for the table. The table is only a header. Here's the code I have for the css and table.

```
 <style>
    table {
        margin-top: 2em;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    table th {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #6688FF, #AACCFF); 
        height: 4em; 
        text-align: center; 
        text-transform: capitalize;
        color:white;
        border:#ccc 1px solid;
    }

    table tr {
        text-align: center;
    }

    table thead {
        position:fixed;
    }
</style>

<table class="head">

        <%--header --%>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>one</th>
                <th>two</th>
                <th>three</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <%--body --%>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're making the thead fixed, it's pulled out of the normal flow. Below, I've demonstrated one way to center it horizontally independent of its surroundings. Otherwise, you're better off making the table fixed, since semantically they should continue their parent / child relationship.

Is there a reason that you're a table for this?

```css
table {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

table th {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #6688FF, #AACCFF); 
  height: 4em; 
  text-align: center; 
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color:white;
  border:#ccc 1px solid;
}

table tr {
  text-align: center;
}

table thead {
  position:fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<table class="head">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>one</th>
      <th>two</th>
      <th>three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I wanted to make a separate table for the header alone since I want the header to be fixed on the page when scrolling through the data table. Your method works but when the window is resized is there anyway to move it with it? I'm using asp.net so the data table is just `HorizontalAlign="Center"`

Comment: So the beauty of this method (and you should be able to test the snippet by hitting the Full Screen button) is that it should always be horizontally centered with this method, even on resize. So no need to worry about responsive updates unless you have other design changes on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

remove position fixed from table thead selector and it should work